# Break table row after some value using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one table and I need when serial number will above the `10` it will again shift to next column serial number will start from `11`.

Here is my code:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
    <colgroup>
       <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
       <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Sl. No</th>
          <th>Generated Code</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="detailsstockid">
        <tr ng-repeat="c in listOfViewCode">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{c.generated_code}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Actually I need the following format.

```
sl no  Generated Code  sl no  Generated Code

1          aaa          11        ssss

2          sss          12        gggg
3          eee
4          cccc
5          tttt
6          bbbb
7          nnnn
8          nnnn
9          bbbb
10         cccc
```

newtable:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" ng-repeat="group in groups" style="float:left" >
<colgroup>
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
<col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
</colgroup>
<thead>
 <tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Generated Code</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="g in group.values">
<td>{{$parent.$index * 10 + $index +  1}}</td>
<td>{{g.generated_code}}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Suppose I have `100` no  of data. When serial number will cross `10`, it will shift to right side with same two column and so on. I am using Angular.js.

Comment: Do you mean [pagination](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging)?

Comment: @JiaJian : No,Not pagination.Suppose first 10 no of will display again those two column will replace to right and serial number will start from 11 and so on.

Comment: @JiaJian : Please check the format.

Comment: Have a look at `ng-switch` and if you can use it somehow with the fact that you will switch when `n/10` is zero.

Comment: @a_pradhan : Can you give any example regarding this.Any way Are you from odisha ?

Comment: @satya Look up the documentation and examples. I have given you a simple example below without using an angular directives. Yes I am from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of going about it, that would work for any number of columns from 1-10 would be to do something like:

```
var newList = [];
for(var i = 0; i<listOfViewCode.length; i++) {
    var index = i+1;
    var listIndex = (i%10);
    var row = newList[listIndex];
    if(row == null) {
        row = [];
    }
    listOfViewCode[i].index = index;

    row.push(listOfViewCode[i]);
    newList[listIndex] = row;
}
```

And then use ng-repeat-start to render.

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in newList">
    <td ng-repeat-start="p in c">{{p.index}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat-end>{{p.generated_code}}</td>     
</tr>
```

Comment: Just tested the code, so now it should be entirely correct

Comment: I did as per you no value is coming.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the best I could come up with was creating multiple tables and using css to give them the appearance of one table...

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQ1NpOa96IpzSncbFSud?p=preview

In your template something like this:

```
<table ng-repeat="group in groups" style="float: left">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><b>Sl. No</b></th>
      <th><b>Generated Code</b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="g in group.values">
    <td>{{$parent.$index * 10 + $index +  1}}</td>
    <td>{{g.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then we need to break up your data into chunks and assign them to a "group"... so in the controller we do something like this:

```
var items = [{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'aaa'},{value: 'aaa'},{value: 'aaa'},{value: 'aaa'},{value: 'aaa'},{value: 'ccc'},{value: 'ccc'},{value: 'ccc'},{value: 'ccc'},{value: 'ccc'},{value: 'ddd'},{value: 'ddd'},{value: 'ddd'},{value: 'ddd'},{value: 'ddd'},{value: 'eee'},{value: 'eee'},{value: 'eee'},{value: 'eee'},{value: 'eee'},{value: 'fff'},{value: 'fff'},{value: 'fff'},{value: 'fff'},{value: 'fff'},{value: 'ggg'},{value: 'ggg'},{value: 'ggg'},{value: 'ggg'},{value: 'ggg'},{value: 'hhh'},{value: 'hhh'},{value: 'hhh'},{value: 'hhh'},{value: 'hhh'},{value: 'iii'},{value: 'iii'},{value: 'iii'},{value: 'iii'},{value: 'iii'}];

$scope.groups = [];

// break the data into chunks of 10
var i,j,temparray,chunk = 10;
for (i=0,j=items.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = items.slice(i,i+chunk);
    $scope.groups.push({values: temparray});
}
```

This will create tables with 10 rows each (with the last one having the remaining rows), side by side (using the style="float: left")... best I could come up with.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @ mkelley : i did as per you and its working as per required but one thing in my table i can not get side by side .I am posting the latest table.Can you please check this?

Comment: I'm not clear on which part you are having trouble with now?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making two tabels, as it looks like what you are really doing.
So make a function that gives you elements 1-10 and one that gives you 10 and above, and then just do as you are already doing.

Alternatively if you really want them in one table, you could make an array that contains an array of elements for each row - so elements that are the samen when element % 10. Eg something like.

```
var newList = [];
for(var i = 0; i<listOfViewCode; i++) {
    var index = i+1;
    var row = newList[i%10];
    if(row == null) {
        row = [];
    }
    row.push(listOfViewCode[i]);
    newList[i%10] = row;
}
```

And then you just have a nested ng-repeat within the ng-repeat and render them.

Update: something like this

It could be something like

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in newList">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].generated_code}}</td>
    <td>{{$index+11}}</td>
    <td>{{c[1].generated_code}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @ Christian :Ok,So how i will manage the view part.Can you please share your view part idea ?

Comment: It could be something like

<tr ng-repeat="c in newList">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].generated_code}}</td>
    <td>{{$index+11}}</td>
    <td>{{c[1].generated_code}}</td>
</tr>

Comment: i also followed the above code but no value is coming.

Comment: What do you mean, no value is comming? You can see that it works here http://jsbin.com/dewocopiwe/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: means only table header is displaying but there are no value is there.

Comment: Try and break the problem up and solve each part. First include the function that I wrote for you, and make sure it is in scope. Then try and repeat over each item and do something simple. Etc. But I would recommend the other answer I gave and use the ng-repeat-start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98078/discussion-between-satya-and-christian-nielsen).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below-:

Code-:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<table  id="dataTable" style="float: left;"  ng-repeat="c in [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]" ng-init="newlist=listOfViewCode.slice(c,c+10)">
    <colgroup>
       <col >
       <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Sl. No</th>
          <th>Generated Code</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="detailsstockid">
        <tr ng-repeat="c in newlist">
            <td>{{$index+c}}</td>
            <td>{{c}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.listOfViewCode=[];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
$scope.listOfViewCode[i]=i+1;
}
}
```

I have just shown an example to help you implement what you are trying to do.Hope this helps.

Comment: I did as per you but no value is coming.

Comment: @ Deep : what link you provided please check this.

Comment: @ Deep: ok i am trying because its DB operation not so easy i am making one and update you soon.

Comment: @satya Here is my full code.Please run it on yourself to see the result,Also fiddle- (http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21230/)

Comment: @ Deep : Ok,but serial number always starting from 1.It should increse after 10 means in 1----10,then 11------21.and so on.

Comment: @satya i have updated that just add  '$index+c'. fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21230/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, which basically involves storing the data as a `n x 10` matrix and using nested loops to make the adjustments.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwfPh/15/

Notice, in the controller, the data is stored in the modified form.